# Cipher Decryption based on letter frequencys - Python

Tags: python

Okay so I need to make a python program that takes an encrypted string and from this works out the English plain text using letter frequency. Now from what I gather I should be taking the string and using string.count to get the frequency although I am stuck from here.

After getting the frequency how can I then say the most frequent letter in the cipher is 'e' so print all of the most frequent letter as 'e', the 2nd most frequent is 't' and so on?

Can anyone give me a few things to look at which could help with the creation of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

code_string = "abcdhjshslsldjhdjh"
letters = Counter(code_string)

print(letters.most_common())
```

results in

```
[('h', 4), ('d', 3), ('j', 3), ('s', 3), ('l', 2), ('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('b', 1)]
```